# Validate data mask

Tags: javascript, jasny-bootstrap, data-masking

I have a problem to validate data- mask.

```
<strike><input type="text" data-mask="a-99999999-9"></strike>
```

I need you where going "a" only become available the letters " VEJPG ".

if anyone knows how it could do so thanks.

Comment: <input type="text" data-mask="a-99999999-9">

Comment: Do you mean using the pattern attribute? `<input pattern="a-[VEJPG]+"/>`. Your question isn't very clear.

Comment: data-mask="a-99999999-9"    "a"= abcdef...  "9"= 012345... I need you where going "a" only become available the letters " VEJPG "

Answer (score 2):

JQuery Mask plugin doesn't recognize "a" in the mask expression, it supports "A"
This will work:

```
<strike><input type="text" data-mask="A-99999999-9"></strike>
```

If you want the first letter to only V or E or J or P or G then you have to call the mask constructor in javascript as follow:

```
$("#idOfTextInput").mask("v-9999999-9",{translation: {'v':{pattern:/[VEJPG]/}}});
```